# Prove that if $f:[a,b]\to[a,b]$ is continuous then there is a $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=c$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am confused by this problem. Is this statement equivalent to the intermediate value theorem? I am pretty sure that I am at least supposed to prove it using IVT, but other than that I am lost.

Comment: What about looking at the function $g\colon x \mapsto f(x)-x$?

Comment: No, it follows from the intermediate value theorem. Consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$.

Comment: That was a typo, I meant to say "Intermediate Value Theorem"

Comment: How is proving $g(x)=0$ any easier?

Comment: Examine $g$ at the end points and hopefully you'll see!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the function given by $g(x)=f(x)-x$. If $f(a)=a$ or $f(b)=b$ we're done. If not, then it must be the cases $a<f(a)$ and $b>f(b)$, so the function $g$ is positive in $a$ and negative in $b$. Since $g$ is continuous because is sum of continuous functions, by the intermediate value theorem, there exists a $c\in(a,b)$ such that $g(c)=0$. But this implies that $f(c)=c$.

Answer (score 0):

This is, of course, the standard method that one expects to learn in a calculus course or elementary analysis course.  But I always worry for the student.  Here is what sometimes happen.

> Student: How do I prove this for the function $f(x)$?  The hint says
>   use IVP.
>
> Professor:  Just take this new function $g(x)$ [which he pulls out of
>   a hat from under his desk].  Apply IVP to the new function. See?
>
> Student: I don't see.  Where did that come from?
>
> Professor: Hmmm.  Well try the next problem.

Often textbooks (and certainly research papers) make no effort to consult the intuition of the student.  These constructions, however, always have a motivation and are not at all as *ad hoc* as they might seem.

In this case the student should sketch the graph of the function $f$.  It all takes place in the square $[a,b]\times[a,b]$.  After a few moments one can see that the line $y=x$ is where our attention is drawn.  By then subtracting the line from the problem (shifting attention to $f(x)-x$) makes some sense.

Any student who feels that the subject is starting to look magical (i.e., functions pulled out of hats or ruder places) should appreciate that there is an intuitive basis for all of what we do.  Just be patient.