# $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a continuous function. Prove there exists a point p an element of $[0,1]$ such that $f(p)=p$

Tags: real-analysis

$f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a continuous function. Prove there exists a point p an element of $[0,1]$ such that $f(p)=p$

I have no idea how to do this but is it asking me for a proof if the intermediate value theorem? 
i'm not entirely sure how the IVT would solve this because it doesn't specify $f(p)=p$.

Comment: please repeat the question in the body of the question!

Comment: @ArnaudMortier And the post I have mentioned is a duplicate of yours.

Comment: @mfl I'd be surprised if this question hasn't been asked 10 times independently already.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier For sure. One more https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501015/prove-that-if-fa-b-toa-b-is-continuous-then-there-is-a-c-ina-b-such-t?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

Think about the function $g(x) = f(x) - x$. What is the sign of $g$ at $0$? What is the sign of $g$ at $1$?